# How to Create Method and Property with Expression Tree Dynamically?

Tags: c#-4.0

This code works but I would like to know whether this is good solution? Would this solution using Expression Tree be considered better than Emit and OpCodes?

```
var target = Expression.Lambda(
            Expression.Block(
                new ParameterExpression[] { },
                Expression.Call(
                    typeof(MessageBox).GetMethod("Show", new[] { typeof(string) }),
                   Expression.Constant(1.ToString(), typeof(string))
                )
            ),
            new ParameterExpression[] { }

        );
AssemblyName aName = new AssemblyName("DynamicAssemblyExample");

AssemblyBuilder ab =
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
                aName,
                AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);

        ModuleBuilder mb =
            ab.DefineDynamicModule(aName.Name, aName.Name + ".dll");
TypeBuilder tb = mb.DefineType("MyDynamicType", TypeAttributes.Public);
        var method = tb.DefineMethod("dynamicMethod", MethodAttributes.Public     |         MethodAttributes.Static);
target.CompileToMethod(method);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in your example seems like just "example" code. I don't see it as requiring expression trees. If I read it correctly it is merely creating the constant expression `() => MessageBox.Show(1.ToString());`.)

Expression trees are great, among others, when actual dynamic code needs to be created i.e. when interpreting some other language within a program or for operations that would otherwise require reflection (e.g. in programs such as Automapper.)

Are they better than emitting the op-codes directly. It really depends: can do a better job than the compiler? Emitting op-codes is like writing assembly, it is time consuming and you really need to know what you are doing to be able to write optimal code. Is the performance difference between compiler and hand optimized code worth the extra effort?

Comment: tanx for your answered but i try to convert my code from OpCodes to Expression Tree and i looking for solution to use Expression Tree for  create dll dynamicly